# Best way of storing images on the server hard-disk in C# WinForm App

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, client-server

As far as I'm concerned, storing images directly in an SQL DB is not the best way. Specially, when there are lots of them with huge space. Experts claim that it’s better to just insert the images name into DB and store images on the H-Disk.

So, I wrote some codes like below which saves images on the H-Disk of the users’ computer:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(PicBoxCustomer.ImageLocation);
    string path = Application.StartupPath + "/Images/";

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    PicBoxCustomer.Image.Save(path + imageName);

    Customers customers = new Customers()
            {
                Address = txtAddress.Text,
                Email = txtEmail.Text,
                FullName = txtName.Text,
                Mobile = txtMobile.Text,
                CustomerImage = imageName
            };

   if (customerId == 0)
   {
       db.CustomerRepository.InsertCustomer(customers);
   }
   else
   {
       customers.CustomerID = customerId;
       db.CustomerRepository.UpdateCustomer(customers);
   }

   db.Save();
}
```

This works fine for a single user, but in the real world, my company has about 1300 personnel (users) and I must find a way that saves images from all users' PC on the Server’s Hard-Disk (not on every users’ computer separately, to have the ability of showing all images to all users).

I have two questions:

1. How should I transfer (upload) images from user's PC via intranet to the server?
2. How should I change above codes to save images on the server hard-disk instead of user's computer?

I'm using LINQ technology (`DataContext`) with a repository design pattern.

Would you please help me to do that?

Comment: Storing images on users machines is absolutely not a good idea! Store your images in the database where other data belongs to. Restrict their sizes if you need to.

Comment: I agree, but some experts and very well-known programmer who are teaching in famous online institute tell their student to do so. I prefer not telling you their name (cause I assume you are Persian) but I'm sure you know them all.

Comment: you are right, but that definitely depends on the size of your object. by storing images outside of db you are risking all the features that a DBMS gives you! you will have maintenance and transaction management issues to name a few. Read this [To BLOB or Not To BLOB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fapps%2Fpubs%2Fdefault.aspx%3Fid%3D64525#!related_info) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, please let me check...

Comment: With great thanks to dear Ali, that article was really beneficial. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You asked multiple questions in this topic and don't say anything about your try and fails.

For the clue you should write the web service which present API to clients to upload the image to server and store theme locally in server, search about WCF or WebAPI to implement the web service in C#.

- Don't store content of the images in database because of increasing the size of database over the time.

Comment: Thanks in advance and sorry for asking multiple question. So, it shows that you agree with the idea of not storing huge images in DB.